# Selenium webdriver-java: how to get the data of tooltip

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

I want to get data of tooltop which shows on move over.

[image]

I have tried

`System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='content']/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/span/div/a")).getAttribute("span"));`

but nothing happened.

HTML:

```
<td data-type="custom_task_name">
<span class="list" sfuuid="2186" data-original-title="">
<div class="ellipsis_inline">
<a href="#Tasks/dab6138c-b2b5-e7e6-a537-52ca491b931e">Task Testing</a>
</div>
</span>
```

I am pretty sure this tooltip is showed by java script.

Comment: Once you mouse over then the attribute data-original-title will contain the tool tip. Get the value of this attribute and you will get the tool tip. Also change the xpath to td[a[text() = 'Task Testing']]/descendant::span[@class='list']

Comment: I have tried below code but nothing shown.
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='content']/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/span/div/a"));
    action.moveToElement(element).build().perform();
    Thread.sleep(5000);
 System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='content']/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/span/div/a")).getAttribute("title"));

Comment: Please use data-original-title instead of title. Also change the xpath to td[a[text() = 'Task Testing']]/descendant::span[@class='list']

Comment: its not working. xPath is not correct but when i use "data-original-title" it shows null:

Actions action = new Actions(driver);
    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='content']/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/span/div/a"));
  
    action.moveToElement(element).build().perform();
    //Thread.sleep(5000);
 System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='content']/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/span/div/a")).getAttribute("data-original-title"));

Comment: I am not sure why is it so difficult to understand. Change both the xpath to what I have told. It should work. There is something wrong in your xpath. I can't say for sure as you have not posted the entire html to create the xpath that you have created.

Comment: its showed org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element
on using Actions action = new Actions(driver);
    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("td[a[text() = 'Task Testing']]/descendant::span[@class='list']"));
  
    action.moveToElement(element).build().perform();
    //Thread.sleep(5000);
 System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("td[a[text() = 'Task Testing']]/descendant::span[@class='list']")).getAttribute("data-original-title"));

Comment: pls add me on Skype my id is adnan.ghaffar07